# Libgdx: Pack file, TextureRegion, and Animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have encountered and NullpointerException in my code. I am trying to use my pack file and store them in the texture region so that I could use as frames for my animation, and every time I try to run it gives me an error. I also tried to setRegion() but it still gives me errors, and the same nullpointerexception, can't seem to find whats wrong. need help in debugging my code.

Here is my code:

```
walking = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("character/dugman/hero.pack"));

wu1 = new TextureRegion(walking.findRegion("heroup1.png"));
wu1.setRegion(10, 10, 10, 10);
wu2 = new TextureRegion(walking.findRegion("heroup2.png"));
wu2.setRegion(10, 10, 10, 10);
wu3 = new TextureRegion(walking.findRegion("heroup3.png"));
wu3.setRegion(10,10,10, 10);

wu = new Animation(0.5f, wu1,wu2,wu3);
wu.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP_PINGPONG);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:100)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.<init>(TextureRegion.java:63)
```

Comment: Try finding the region without the .png extension. I think the packer removes the extension.

Comment: Jeremy is right. For more clarification u can open your pack file in your editor for a better explanation of how things are done

Comment: I got it already, plus the its upper case sensitive. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For future seekers:

As I said in my comment - the packer removes the file extension. You added that the region names are also case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Animation image Frames on .pack file is better to be with same name you may manually rename names.